# Is there a way to set a trigger on Blockfrost to know when an asset has been moved?

Tags: blockfrost

With Blockfrost, I can easily query which assets belong to a staking address using `/accounts/{stake_address}/addresses/assets`. I would like to use this approach to allow users to associate their accounts with an ADA Handle. However, I don't see an easy way to check when the Handle has been moved to a different wallet (besides querying Blockfrost every x hours). Is there a better approach using Blockfrost? Should I look into hosting a node instead?

---

Using [Tango](https://www.tangocrypto.com/) (so not Blockfrost), this should be possible in two weeks. See [here](https://docs.tangocrypto.com/notify/notify/trigger-rules#nft-rules-coming-soon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Blockfrost offers event based callbacks like that. You might want to look into tangocrypto, but as far as I can tell they also don't offer webhooks for this specific type of event: https://docs.tangocrypto.com/notify/notify/using-webhooks#types-of-wehooks

Maybe it's worth getting in touch with them as I think it could potentially be an interesting addition for their service.

The other option would be to set up a cardano node, as you said, and connect a [db-sync (postgres)](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-db-sync) instance which you can query.

Comment: I contacted both Blockfrost and Tango about this feature, so hopefully at least one of them will consider adding it. In the meantime, looks like I'll be setting up a node and db-sync. Thanks for your help!